# Is it possible to replace leading zeroes in a string with an equal number of spaces using replaceAll()?

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I'm trying to replace strings like "001.234" with "spacespace1.234". However, I'm a regex noob and I seem to be ending up with all leading zeroes replaced by a single space.

I understand that I can do this easily with a loop but I'm trying to pick up regular expressions and appreciate any help :)

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: replaceAll("^0*0", " ") seems to replace all leading zeroes with a space. I think I see why it is happening though. I then tried some crazy combinations using whatever little I know - [], ^, $, () etc. but none of them seem to be doing what I need.

Comment: You could have spared us some confusion by providing test cases with zeroes that *shouldn't* be replaced, like `010.234` and `001.2034`.  In fact, negative examples are often much more helpful than positive ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No problem:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\G0", " ");
```

`\G` acts like `\A` (the start-of-string anchor) on the first iteration of `replaceAll()`, but on subsequent passes it anchors the match to the spot where the previous match ended.  That prevents it from matching zeroes anywhere else in the string, like after the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you so much! This does exactly what I need. Not sure why someone downvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do replace

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String before = "00000001.234";

        String after = before.replaceAll("0", " ");

        System.out.println("This is after :"+after+" replacing");
    }
```

Output: `This is after :       1.234 replacing`

Comment: Did you try that? It'll replace the *whole* sequence of zeros with a single space.

Comment: Yes I tried and replace and replaceAll both will work. The output is the output of my program

Comment: Now it works, because you're using the right regex, which is simply `0`. But note that this will replace zeros in the middle of the String as well..

Comment: I believe the question was asked for only replacing the leading zeroes, not any other zeros that may occur in the middle or end or the string. Your program would replace all zeroes, irrespective of the position