# Replace leading zeros till decimal point with dash

Tags: java, regex, formatting

If a string is `a = 000102.45600`. I need to convert it to `a = ---102.45600`.
Any help in java using either regex or String formatter?

Tried the following:

```
a = a.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)","-");
```

but i am getting only `a = -102.45600` not 3 dashes.

Rules: Any leading zeros before decimal in string should be replaced by that many dashes.

1. `000023.45677` to `----23.45677`
2. `002345.56776` to `--2345.56776`
3. `00000.45678` to `-----.45678`

Hopefully I am clear on what my need is?

Comment: post your attempt

Comment: You  won't get any help unless you post what you have tried so far.

Comment: yourString.replaceAll("000([1-9]\\d{2}\\.)", "---\\1");

Comment: @LYF_HKN That very clearly doesn't generalize

Comment: Remove the plus and change to re.replaceAll()

Comment: Thanks All folks.

Comment: @RohanMeher You accepted my answer and then? Did you find any problem in that?

Comment: @WasiAhmad I thanked everybody for their immediate help. Anything wrong?

Comment: @RohanMeher no, its completely fine. you accepted my answer but later changed your pick for the accepted answer. so, i was just wondering whether you have found any problem in my suggested solution. i just want to suggest you, if you liked an answer, stick to it. anyway, nothing to worry.

Comment: @WasiAhmad Ohk I got it now. I am new to stack-overflow hence the confusion. I got what you meant when you say "later changed". I opted for what is correct and efficient and that's yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String subjectString = "000102.45600";
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\G0", "-");
System.out.println(resultString); // prints ---102.45600
```

`\G` acts like `\A` (the start-of-string anchor) on the first iteration of `replaceAll()`, but on subsequent passes it anchors the match to the spot where the previous match ended.  That prevents it from matching zeroes anywhere else in the string, like after the decimal point.

See: reference SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30554924/5352399).

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm. Any good tutorial where I can learn regex in interactive manner.

Comment: welcome! there are plenty of tutorials but i personally prefer tutorialspoint - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm. its easy to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
String number = //assign a value here
    for (int i=number.length();i>0; i--) {
        if (number.substring(0,i).matches("^0+$")) {
            System.out.println(number.replaceAll("0","-"));
            break;
        }
    }
```

This searches for the longest substring of `number` which starts at index 0 and consists entirely of zeroes - starting by checking the entire String, then shortening it until it finds the longest substring of leading zeroes. Once it finds this substring, it replaces each zero with a dash and breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Works !  But I think Wasi Ahmed answer is more preferred in this case. Less line of codes less prone to error.

Answer (score -2):

Why not convert the start of the string to the "." to an integer, convert it back to a string then compare the lengths. 000102 length = 6. 102 length = 3. You would have your preceding zero count.

Comment: No offence If i would have to do the way you proposed I would not have come here for solution. Utility are meant to be learnt and stack overflows helps in that regard.